# Remove multiple rows with same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So I've done some looking around and wasn't unable to find quite what I was looking for. I have two tables.

1.) Table where general user information is stored

2.) Where a status is generated and stored.

The problem is, is that there are multiple rows for the same users and querying these results in multiple returns. I can't just merge them because they aren't all the same status. I need just the newest status from that table.

Example of the table:
[image: Table of Users and Status]

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   TOP(50) cam.UserID AS PatientID,
   mppi.DisplayName AS Surgeon,
   ISNULL(sci.IOPStatus, 'N/A') AS Status,
   tkstat.TrackerStatusID AS Stat_2
FROM
   Main AS cam 
   INNER JOIN
      Providers AS rap 
      ON cam.VisitID = rap.VisitID 
   INNER JOIN
      ProviderInfo AS mppi 
      ON rap.UnvUserID = mppi.UnvUserID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      Inop AS sci 
      ON cam.CwsID = sci.CwsID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      TrackerStatus AS tkstat 
      ON cam.CwsID = tkstat.CwsID 
WHERE
   (
      cam.Location_ID IN 
      (
         'SURG'
      )
   )
   AND 
   (
      rap.IsAttending = 'Y'
   )
   AND 
   (
      cam.DateTime BETWEEN CONCAT(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), ' 23:59:59')
   )
   AND 
   (
      cam.Status_StatusID != 'Cancelled'
   )
ORDER BY
   cam.UserID ASC
```

So I need to grab only the newest Stat_2 from each ID so they aren't returning multiple rows. Each Stat_2 also has an update time meaning I can sort by the time/date that column is : **StatusDateTime**

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? (That query looks more like MS SQL Server.)

Comment: @jarlh, I am using MS SQL. I've adjusted my tags. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this is to create a calculated row_number for the table where you need the newest  record.

Easiest way to do that is to change your TKSTAT join to a *derived table* with the row_number calculation and then add a constraint to your join where the RN =1

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (50)
    cam.UserID AS PatientID, mppi.DisplayName AS Surgeon, ISNULL(sci.IOPStatus, 'N/A') AS Status, tkstat.TrackerStatusID AS Stat_2
FROM Main AS cam
INNER JOIN Providers AS rap ON cam.VisitID = rap.VisitID
INNER JOIN ProviderInfo AS mppi ON rap.UnvUserID = mppi.UnvUserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Inop AS sci ON cam.CwsID = sci.CwsID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT tk.CwsID, tk.TrackerStatusId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tk.cwsId ORDER BY tk.CreationDate DESC) AS rn FROM TrackerStatus tk)AS tkstat ON cam.CwsID = tkstat.CwsID
    AND tkstat.rn = 1 
WHERE (cam.Location_ID IN ( 'SURG' )) AND (rap.IsAttending = 'Y')
    AND (cam.DateTime BETWEEN CONCAT(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), ' 23:59:59'))
    AND (cam.Status_StatusID != 'Cancelled')
ORDER BY cam.UserID ASC;
```

Note you need a way to derive what the "newest" status is; I assume there is a created_date or something; you'll need to enter the correct colum name

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tk.cwsId ORDER BY tk.CreationDate DESC) AS rn
```

Comment: It appears to have created more tables? It doesn't seem like it's limiting it to the 1 row. After making these adjustments I now have 22 tables instead of only 14.

Comment: Hmm... what do the results look like? Do you have a created_date in the tkstat table or a way to identify the 'newest' record?

Comment: @Arron, I've updated the post with the changes.

Comment: I figured out that I never removed the original INNER JOIN for Tkstat. After doing so this is working fine now! :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't offer a FIRST function, but you can reproduce the functionality with ROW_NUMBER() like this:

```
With Qry1 (
    Select      <other columns>, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY <group by columns> 
                    ORDER BY <time stamp column*> DESC
                ) As Seq
    From        <the rest of your select statement>
)
Select      * 
From        Qry1
Where       Seq = 1
```

* for the "newest" record.